# Logitech unifying adapter with K520 Keyboard and M310 Mouse not working?

Tags: 12.10, usb, mouse, logitech, logitech-unifying

Everywhere that I have read online has said that as long as the devices are paired to the adapter first on a windows machine using the unifying software that it would work fine, so I have done that, and it works fine on windows.

However on Ubuntu nothing is making the adapter work.

Plugging in the adapter gives this output in `dmesg`:

```
[ 2435.192014] usb 3-2: >new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2435.210390] usb 3-2: >New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[ 2435.210395] usb 3-2: >New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2435.210399] usb 3-2: >Product: USB Receiver
[ 2435.210402] usb 3-2: >Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 2435.216076] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.001F: >hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[ 2435.216363] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.001F: logi_dj_probe:logi_dj_recv_query_paired_devices error:-32
[ 2435.216598] logitech-djreceiver: probe of 0003:046D:C52B.001F failed with error -32
```

I tried following [this guide](http://outhereinthefield.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/logitech-unifying-receiver-on-ubuntu/) and in the end ran `sudo /opt/unify/pairing_tool /dev/hidraw0` but the output is:

```
Unable to open device: No such file or directory
```

---

Ok, so I have found a "fix" basically, re plugging the adapter into a different usb port (doesn't always work, so I have to loop between my ports, sometimes ending up with it working on the original port!).

On the times when it fails it displays that same -32 error message in `dmesg`

Comment: Bug related to USB 3.0 (see duplicate), http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg25135.html